# IPSec tunnel with pfSense networking issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, nat, pfsense

I'm having networking issues with a pfSense appliance launched from AWS market place. The network looks something like this:

[image: Approximate configuration]

- We connect to our customer checkpoint appliance. They require that we provide a public IP to route *inside* our side of the VPN.
- Inbound only machine, only accepts incomming connections from our side of the VPN
- Outbound only, can establish a connection from the customer's side, but not the other way around.
- The tunnel uses IKEv1

Current configuration of pfSense:

- A port forward NAT rule changes de destination IP address from 3.3.3.3 to 172.1.1.2
- An outbound NAT from network 10.1.0.0/16 converts the source IP to 172.1.1.1 (which is the private IP of the pfSense)
- Another outbound NAT sets the source to 3.3.3.3 for packets intended to 10.1.0.0/16

Current configuration of VPN / Sec groups:

- Both pfSense and 172.1.1.2 are in the same subnet, and the same SG
- SG allows all traffic within the SG
- A routing table sends packets intended to 10.1.0.0/16 to the ENI in the pfSense (also tried to add a route directly in 172.1.1.2 to pfSense)

The situation now is like this:

- The tunnel establishes successfully
- From outbound only, I can access the application server
- From the pfSense box, I can access inbound only
- **From the app server at 172.1.1.2 I cannot access inbound only** as I would expect

More info:

- tcpdumps in 172.1.1.2 show packets trying to SYN with 10.1.1.1. When setting the routing table in 172.1.1.2 for 10.1.0.0/16 via 172.1.1.1, I can see the MAC of pfSense in the dataframe destination.
- tcpdumps in pfSense interface *do not show* packets comming from 172.1.1.2
- tcpdumps in IPSec interface in pfSense do not show packets intended for 10.1.1.1
- VPC flow logs show packets accepted going out of the ENI 172.1.1.2
- VPC flow logs do not show packets comming in the ENI in pfSense intended for 10.1.1.1

Given all the above, it seems to me like AWS networking is discarding the packets, but I can't figure out why.

Any ideas what I can try to connecto to `inbound only` from `172.1.1.2`?

Thank you!

Comment: I partially resolved it with a squid reverse proxy in pfSense, but would like to resolve it definitely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS routing "lost" packets intended to a network behind VPN](https://serverfault.com/questions/1052019/aws-routing-lost-packets-intended-to-a-network-behind-vpn)

Comment: Yehp! Actually that is also my question, which I tried to rephrase because I realized that it was not VPN-related but AWS-related. Thanks for pointing it out!