# AWS routing "lost" packets intended to a network behind VPN

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have an EC2 instance that connects to a VPN and another instance in the same VPC that emmits traffic to that VPN

So the topology is something like this:
[image: network topology]

- The instance at 172.1.0.1 can connect to the remote VPN (192.168.1.0/24) without any issues.
- The instances within the VPC can connect to each other.
- Instances i-aaaa and i-bbbb **cannot** connecto to machines in 192.168.1.0/24

Current configuration looks like this:

- The route table in the VPC has an entry for 192.168.1.0/24 via i-0000
- The sec group allows all traffic within the security group
- All instances in the VPC are in the same security group

I have configured flow logs in the VPC and notice that I can see traffic going out of the ENI at i-bbbb but there is no traffic in the ENI at i-0000

Also, packet capture in i-0000 does not show any packet comming from any of the other instances with dst to 192.168.1.0/24

So this raises some questions:

- Would AWS drop packets because they are not in the same CIDR as the rest of the VPC? (My guess is not)
- How can I troubleshoot where are packets being dropped? Everything suggests that packets are dropped within the VPC by AWS
- What else can I try to make it work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is **Source / destination check** - EC2 instances perform source and destination checks by default. The instance must be the *source* or *destination* of all the traffic it sends and receives. That obviously isn't true for gateways like in your case. Hence you have to **Stop** the *Source / destination check*

First select your instance:

[image: Source / destination check]

Then *Stop* the check:

[image: Stop the check]

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Awesome!! That was it!! Thank you!!